# Creating a new email in Outlook including email body text

Tags: outlook, outlook-2003

On a corporate intranet where all of our users are using Outlook 2003 I have a need to allow a user to click a link that opens a new email window with a prepopulated message body, subject and To line. The body text requirement eliminates a simple option like a MailTo link.

I know there is an EML format Outlook uses, but I don't see how to use it to open a message that displays like a new email message being sent by the user. It seems to just be a format for archiving emails in a regular folder.

Are there other options? Other file formats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you **CAN** use mailto and have a message in the body.

http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html

Comment: For some reason I had no idea you could edit the body text. I'll look further in to this to see if I can understand how to do more formatting beyond text and line breaks, but this gets me going. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported properly across other mail clients/webmail clients but if Outlook is your only audience you can try the following:

```
<a href="mailto:hello@company.com&#046;co&#046;uk?subject=Your Email Subject&amp;body=This is the first line and then a line break%0AThis is the second line">Link</a>
```

You need to ensure that any characters are encoded properly (full stops, ampersands etc)